# How to change label after close form

Tags: c#, winforms

When I start app form1 labelStatus = "Can't Edit" and after I click btnedit form2 is open
and
**labelStatus = "Editable "**; but after I close form2 by button close on windows it don't  change

back labelStatus to "Can't Edit"  again

**Form1**

```
public static string txt;
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            editForm edit= new editForm();
            editForm.Show();
            labelStatus.Text = "";

        }
```

In form1
Where I should put labelStatus.Text=txt;

**Form2**

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            Form1.txt = "Can't Edit";
            
        }
```

Comment: Its because you don't pass the reference of Form1 to Form2. You can either pass a reference to Form2 about Form1 or you can respond to the FormClosed event on Form1

Comment: @craig1231  please guide me

Comment: You can also open `form2` as dialog... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0

Comment: editForm.FormClosed += (s, ea) => labelStatus.Text = "Can't edit";

Answer (score 0):

Find `Form1` by `Form1` name from `OpenForms` in **Appliction**

use following code

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Where(x => x.Name == "formName").FirstOrDefault();
    form1.labelStatus.Text = "Can't Edit";
}
```